# what is the difference between angular.isUndefined(value) and not !(value)?

Tags: angularjs

I've tried:

```
if(angular.isUndefined(value)){
    // something
}
```

and

```
if(!(value)){
    // something
}
```

- Is there a difference between the two?
- Is there a use-case to choose one instead of the other?

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = false; 


if(!foo) {
  // will log
  console.log("foo is defined but false");
}

if(angular.isUndefined(foo)){
   // will not log as foo is defined
   console.log("foo is undefined")
}
```

another example without define foo

```
if(!foo) {
  // will throw exception "Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined "
  console.log("foo is defined but false");
}

if(angular.isUndefined(foo)){
   // will log
   console.log("foo is undefined")
}
```

so effective angular.isUndefined(foo)  does nothing else than evaluating

```
if(typeof foo == "undefined")
```

wrapped for saving 1 character yeah.

while !-operator checks if a defined variable evaluates to false
so

```
if(!foo)
```

is the same like

```
if( foo != true)
```

UPDATE:

As stated in comments, when i write "evaluates to false" there is `false` `null` `undefined` `NaN` `""`(empty string)  and `0` included

Comment: Correct. And there are other things that are coerced to false, like null.

Answer (score 0):

! is the logical not operator in JavaScript while angular.isUndefined(value) checks if the reference is undefined

Which one to use completely depends on what you are trying to do in the end.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isUndefined